What means -z ${var+x}?
I would like to know what means -z ${var+x}
if [ -z ${VAR+x} ]; then
   echo "Variable VAR is unset."
else
   echo "VAR = ${VAR}."

I would like to understand in which case I should use this command.
I would like to understand in which case I should use this command.

See Bash's Parameter Expansion

This is badly written code. It should be either [ -z "${VAR+x}" ] or [[ -z ${VAR+x} ]], unless you enjoy gambling. If you use [, the -z is described when you do a man test. For the +x part, you look at man bash and search for a section titled Parameter Expansion, where ${parameter:+word} is described by: Use  Alternate  Value.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

Instead of testing against the result of an expansion that only occurs if the variable is set by using + (or set and not empty by using :+), just directly test if the variable is set by using ? (or set and not empty by using :?).

Does this answer your question? What does -z mean in Bash?

BTW, the code as posted fails, if VAR contains spaces, or has the value x. Don't tell me that you found this in real, productive code???

See How to check if a variable is set in Bash and How to check if a variable is set in Bash.

-z checks for "emptiness"
${...} is parameter expansion
${VAR+x} evaluates this expression to x, if VAR is set and not empty.
So if VAR is set and not empty, your expression evaluates to false (so this code runs : echo "VAR = ${VAR}."), otherwise it evaluates to true (so this code runs: echo "Variable VAR is unset.")
It's one way to check if VAR is set and not empty.

Minor detail: ${v+x} already evaluates to x if v is just set, regardless of it being empty or not. To have it evaluated if v is set and not empty, you'd use :+ instead: ${v:+x}.
